# Asynchronously Downloading The Image From Parse

Tags: image, swift2, asynchronous

I'm trying to download images from parse via 'Asynchronously'.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    var cell:CatsTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CatsTableViewCell

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CatsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil) [0] as? CatsTableViewCell
    }

    if let pfObject = object {
        cell?.catNameLabel?.text = pfObject["name"] as? String

        var votes:Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
        if votes == nil {
            votes = 0
        }
        cell?.catVotesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"

        var credit:String? = pfObject["cc_by"] as? String
        if credit != nil {
            cell?.catCreditLabel?.text = "\(credit!) / CC 2.0"
        }
        cell?.catImageView?.image = nil

        if var urlString:String? = pfObject["url"] as? String {
            var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!)

            if var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!) {
                var error:NSError?
                var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().cancelAllOperations()

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                    (response:NSURLResponse?, imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                    cell?.catImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                })
            }
        }
```

---

now I changed few code

```
completionHandler: {
                    (response:NSURLResponse!, imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                    cell?.catImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

to

```
completionHandler: {
                    (response:NSURLResponse?, imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                    cell?.catImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

---

and no critical errors but the image doesn't show up on the simulator.
Any help would be appreciate. Thank you all.

---

-first problem-

*And the problem is occurred down below
    cell?.catImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
it says

> Value of optional type ‘()?’ not unwrapped; did you mean to use ‘!’ or ‘?’?*

Answer (score 0):

The initializer init(data:) returns an optional UIImage. You should check and unwrap it:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
(response: NSURLResponse?, imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let e = error {
        print(e)
        return
    }
    guard let data = imageData else { return }
    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        cell?.catImageView?.image = image
    }

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But after that I got this problem 

it says - 
_**Cannot convert value of type '(NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type '(NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void'**_

`NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {`

[link](http://postimg.org/image/9xg5pqk8t/) <- here is the image

Comment: @YoungSunChoi, i just copied your code and i'm wondering why this worked without errors in your example. The parameters in completion handler must be optionals. Just edited my answer.

Comment: Actually I have no idea why it worked in my example. But even though, if that is the case then I could do this way. But if I do that then the code succeeded without error, except no image downloaded from 'Parse' or maybe I'm doing something wrong
`completionHandler: {
                        (response:NSURLResponse?, imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
cell?.catImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)`

Comment: @YoungSunChoi, as a said, UIImage(data:) returns an optional. You must unwrap it like UIImage(data: imageData!)! However, this is not the right way, because imageData can be nil and you will get a runtime error. You should first to check if there was an error and then try to unwrap imageData and then create UIImage instance as I mentioned in my answer.